# Plotting multiple functions using values in a list

Tags: python

This is the gist of what I need to do: in python, I have a parametric function f(x(t,omega),y(t,omega)) where omega has five specific values (at non-regular intervals). What I want to do is basically plot this function f on the same plot for each of the five values of omega.

Now, I have a working code for this but I think that it could be more concise (and I'm very interested in knowing HOW it could be more concise, because I want to learn as much as I can about python from this exercise), and also, I can't figure out how to fix the range of x(t,omega) here! This last point is the most problematic.

Here is my "working" code:

```
x=linspace(0,10,100)
H0=71
omega0=1.01
Rc=0.5*(omega0/(omega0-1))*(1-cos(x))
tc=(0.5/H0)*(omega0/(omega0-1)**(3/2))*(x-sin(x))
plot(tc,Rc)
omega0=1.1
Rc=0.5*(omega0/(omega0-1))*(1-cos(x))
tc=(0.5/H0)*(omega0/(omega0-1)**(3/2))*(x-sin(x))
plot(tc,Rc)
omega0=1.5
Rc=0.5*(omega0/(omega0-1))*(1-cos(x))
tc=(0.5/H0)*(omega0/(omega0-1)**(3/2))*(x-sin(x))
plot(tc,Rc)
omega0=2.0
Rc=0.5*(omega0/(omega0-1))*(1-cos(x))
tc=(0.5/H0)*(omega0/(omega0-1)**(3/2))*(x-sin(x))
plot(tc,Rc)
omega0=3.0
Rc=0.5*(omega0/(omega0-1))*(1-cos(x))
tc=(0.5/H0)*(omega0/(omega0-1)**(3/2))*(x-sin(x))
plot(tc,Rc)
show()
```

as you can see, tc and Rc serve as my x(t,omega) and y(t,omega) and I've used x as my parametric variable, because...well, I already have a t in the form of tc. If you plot this you'll see that it's difficult to get much information out of it even though all the lines are technically there. Any help is much appreciated!

EDIT: I got what I needed. For anyone coming across this thread because they have similar issues, my revised code thanks in large part to the below answer and some further searching is:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
from pylab import *

x=linspace(0,50,1000)
H0=71 #units km/s/Mpc
omegas = [1.01,1.1,1.5,2.0,3.0]
Rcs = [0.5*(omega0/(omega0-1))*(1-cos(x)) for omega0 in omegas]
tcs = [(0.5/H0)*(omega0/(omega0-1)**(3/2))*(x-sin(x)) for omega0 in omegas]
for pair in zip(tcs,Rcs):
        pl.plot(pair[0],pair[1])
pl.xlim(0,0.55)
pl.ylim(0,60)
pl.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most apparent way to reduce redundancy in your code is to use a for loop or list comprehension:

```
x=linspace(0,10,100)
H0 = 71
omegas = [1.01,1.1,1.5,2.0,3.0]
rcs = [0.5*(omega0/(omega0-1))*(1-cos(x)) for omega0 in omegas]
tcs = [(0.5/H0)*(omega0/(omega0-1)**(3/2))*(x-sin(x)) for omega0 in omegas]
for pair in zip(tcs,rcs):
    plot(pair[0],pair[1])
show()
```

Comment: What a difference! I was trying to implement a for loop and I couldn't get the syntax down...this is perfect, thank you so much.